# How to display custom DOM element in particular position of agm-map

Tags: html, css, angular, google-maps

I'm going to display custom dom into agm-map in my angular6 project.
When I use agm-marker I can only display specific icon and label.
What I want to display looks like:

```css
.user-location i {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.user-location img {
  border-radious: 100%;
}
...
```

```html
<a class="user-location">
  <i class="pin-icon"></i>
  <figure>
    <img src="../../assets/layouts/layout/img/new-icon.png" alt="" />
  </figure>
  ...
</a>
```

Comment: I only see `---` in you output. You wan a custom icon on instead of the native marker?

Comment: Yes. I want to display not only custom icon but also particular elements as I mentioned which means I want to edit style of imgs or icons like border-radious and margin.

Comment: In agm-marker there are only properties like size, not detailed styles

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the marker the following way:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"  [styles]="mapStyle === 'dark' ? styleDark : styleLight">
            <div  *ngFor="let marker of markers;">
                <agm-marker [iconUrl]="'/assets/markers/'+marker.type+'.png'" [latitude]="marker.lat" [longitude]="marker.long" (markerClick)='openMarkerInfo(markerInfo, marker)'>           
                </agm-marker>
            </div>
        </agm-map>
```

If you ever want to customize the map too you can do the following:

```
[styles]="mapStyle === 'dark' ? styleDark : styleLight"
```

in your ts file you will have all the properties. To learn more about how to customize a map with icons and colors in the map take a look to this repo:
https://github.com/devpato/SOSmap

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying
I checked the repo
But there aren't any codes to style agm-marker.
I want to edit styles of icons like border-radious, border-color, margin and so on.
How can I change the style.
If it's impossible in agm-marker can you solve this problem in other way?